# Is there a way to do "svn switch" in Netbeans 7.4?

Tags: svn, netbeans

I am trying to figure out how to do [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)  in NetBeans 7.4. So far I could not find any reference in on-line how to do this. Do we really have to switch between branches from the command-line or there is some way to do this with the NetBeans Subversion plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out (typical, huh?) that I did not pay attention to the `Subversion -> Copy`. It has a submenu "Switch to Copy..." which does exactly what I want. - It asks user to pick a branch and after pressing OK your working copy will track the chosen branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
Edit: Similarly in RapidSVN,in menu Repository->switch URL 
option will be there,here we can give new URL of 
SVN repository and check the relocate option. ``
```

Comment: I am not relocating. I just want my working directory to start tracking another branch.